# ngx-translate with Angular 9 not working in IE showing compilation error SCRIPT1002

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, ngx-translate

After importing **TranslateModule** into my app module I am seeing an error in Internet Explorer **SCRIPT1002** and when navigate to that line I am seeing a **class TranslateLoader**(there is the problem, IE doesn't know about class).

My app is working in IE without that library so doesn't seem to be a polyfills issue there.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Using IE11.
Happens in both dev mode and prod mode.

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal sample which can reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue so that we can hava a test. Without any code, we can't locate the issue. Besides, have you tried the answer below and does it work?

Comment: yes, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the proper solution but it worked for me:
I have downgraded ngx translate core and http-loader versions as follows:

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "^12.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^5.0.0"
```

Comment: Great. Seems like is a problem with latest version of ngx-translate. Thanks.