# ngx-translate with Angular 9 not working in IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, ngx-translate

Our App don't work in the IE, it's showing only a compilation error (SCRIPT1002) and when navigate to that line it shows the class `TranslateLoader`.

I have already found a similar question about this, unfortunately the answer doesn't work: [ngx-translate with Angular 9 not working in IE showing compilation error SCRIPT1002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012741/ngx-translate-with-angular-9-not-working-in-ie-showing-compilation-error-script1)

Any help would be great. Many thanks.

**package.json**

```
"@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
.....
"@ngx-translate/core": "^12.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^5.0.0",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
```

**browserlist**

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
...
"module": "es2015",
"downlevelIteration": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom"
]
```

**polyfills.ts**

```
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a similar thread](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/1226) and I followed the solution in it then it can work well in IE 11. I use ngx-translate like this [simple sample](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example). You could refer to my files:

**package.json**

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
...
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

The result in IE 11 is like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, with the version 11.0.1 of ngx-translate it's work!